# Filter to NSFetchRequest

Tags: swift, entity, fetch

hi i'm not really understanding how the fetch filter works can anyone help me please? So i currently have this as my fetchall function which displays all of my items within my entity

im having trouble of filtering only one attribute which is a boolean. I want it to only display attributes that are true.

thankyou!

```
 func fetchAllItems(){
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AllItems")

        do{
            let result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
            beastList = result as! [AllItems]
        } catch { print("\(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set the `predicate` (`NSPredicate`) to your request. Also avoid using swift<version> tag unless your question is specific to a version. Instead use the `swift` tag

Comment: thank you for your response, im still stuck on how to use predicate is there any helpful guide that you know of? or can you show me where i would insert predicate? not sure how i am suppose to set predicare to my request. w

Comment: Refer the overview section in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate and https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Answer (score 2):

## Code:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AllItems")

request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "something = %@", argumentArray: [true])
```

**Note:** Replace `something` with your boolean field name

#### Better way to create request

```
let request : NSFetchRequest<AllItems> = AllItems.fetchRequest()
```

#### Naming convention:

It is better to name your entity in singular form, so that each row in your entity could be in singular form.

`AllItems` seems very generic, if you are storing cars, the entity name could be `Car`. The variable that stores the result of the fetch request could be `cars`.

## Reference:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate
- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html